# Converting single column with strings with separator ('|') to multiple columns with binary values based on the string value

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have one million records of data frame with a column, which contains multiple combined strings with a delimiter as a separator .

In the required data frame ,I need to retain the column  and have multiple column hosting the separated strings as column heading with binary values based on the combinations available in the row.

This is required to combine with other features to feed the model estimator.

Sample of the data is enclosed for reference.

```
x.head(20)
Genres
793754  Drama|Sci-Fi
974374  Drama|Romance
950027  Horror|Sci-Fi
998553  Comedy
757593  Action|Thriller
943002  Comedy|Romance
699895  Drama|Romance
228740  Animation|Comedy|Thriller
365470  Comedy
174365  Comedy|Fantasy
827401  Drama
75922   Comedy|Drama
934548  Animation|Children's|Comedy|Musical|Romance
281451  Comedy|Sci-Fi
694344  Sci-Fi
731063  Action|Adventure
978029  Animation|Comedy
283943  Drama|Sci-Fi|Thriller
961082  Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi
778922  Action|Crime|Romance
```

The columns (18 nos) required is extracted as a list from the entire data with unique function and furnished to populate the binary 0 or 1 based on the row string data.

```
genre_movies=list(genre_movies.stack().unique())
genre_movies
['Drama',
 'Animation',
 "Children's",
 'Musical',
 'Romance',
 'Comedy',
 'Action',
 'Adventure',
 'Fantasy',
 'Sci-Fi',
 'War',
 'Thriller',
 'Crime',
 'Mystery',
 'Western',
 'Horror',
 'Film-Noir',
 'Documentary']
```

I am novice to Pandas and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check if this is what you want:
(I have to manually input the genres so I only put 3 lines there)

```
               Genres  Drama  Sci-Fi  Romance  Horror
793754   Drama|Sci-Fi   True    True    False   False
974374  Drama|Romance   True   False     True   False
950027  Horror|Sci-Fi  False    True    False    True
```

the code is :

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame( {
                    'Genres' : ['Drama|Sci-Fi', 'Drama|Romance' , 'Horror|Sci-Fi']
                    },
                    index = [793754, 974374, 950027] , 
                    )
genre_movies=list(df.Genres.unique())
genre_movies2  = [words for segments in genre_movies for words in segments.split('|')]
# get a list of unique genres

for genre in genre_movies2:
    df[genre] = df.Genres.str.contains(genre, regex=False)
```

method 2 suggested by @Ins_hunter
use  `.get_dummies()` method

```
df2 = df.Genres.str.get_dummies(sep='|')

Action  Adventure   Animation   Children's  Comedy  Crime   Documentary Drama   Fantasy Film-Noir   Horror  Musical Mystery Romance Sci-Fi  Thriller    War Western
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1000204 0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1000205 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
1000206 0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1000207 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1000208 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
1000209 rows × 18 columns
```

and it can be merged back to the original data

```
df3 = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```

Comment: @fenixano  Thanks for your response. Yes i need in the same fashion but as 1's and 0's and totally we have 18 such features (so 18 or 17 columns) with binary values. The complete data set is having one million observations.

Comment: @fenixano -     I tried with my existing generated list of unique values -genre_movies    .The code as below.                                                                                                          
           for genre in genre_movies:
                   x['Genres']=x['Genres'].str.contains(genre,regex=False)                               But getting an error as below."AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values! " .Appreciate your Guidance please to conclude...

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes i need in the same fashion but as 1's and 0's  (so 18 or 17 columns) with binary values.  tried with my existing generated list of unique values -genre_movies .The code as below                                                                                                                               . for genre in genre_movies:     x['Genres']=x['Genres'].str.contains(genre,regex=False)  But getting an error as below."AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values! " .Appreciate your Guidance please to conclude...

Comment: @Ins_hunter   1, True is equal to 1 and False is 0, you can sum it the same way.  if you specificly need int 1 and 0, you can use `.astype(int)`   2,  you didn't provide the data so I can not get the 18 columns, I mannually input 4 as demo.   3,  you got error because the code is in the for loop, so you can not run it indivadually.  if you can provide at least a clip of the dataframe that I can import to python, I can directly modify the code so you can run it.  otherwise you need to modify it by yourself.    I don't know if you dataframe is named "x" or "genre_movies" or somthing else

Comment: @fenixano-Thanks for your response .Updated the details of the data frame. The structure got distorted during pasting and sorry for the same. Trying to run KNN but system gets hanged when i run the             y_pred=knn.predict(X_test)          
    statement

Comment: @fenixnano--Thanks for your response .Updated the details of the data frame. The structure got distorted during pasting and sorry for the same. Trying to run KNN but system gets hanged when i run the y_pred=knn.predict(X_test) statemen

Comment: @Ins_hunter  I still can not access your dataframe by any approach, so I can not help you directly.  and I don't know what's your requirement of the KNN you are using.  can you:  1, provide a downloadable dataframe; 2, describe the details of the required data structure, or paste your following KNN code here so I can test run them

Comment: @fenixnano- Actually i had attached the screen shots of the data in the code snippet to understand the data structure.but it is showing pending review as of now. Is there any way to attach the files. Please guide me and help... Prior to feeding the model used (OneHotEncoder()) for fit and transform X and (LabelEncoder()) for y . Then run the model with       knn=KNeighborsClassifier()    knn.fit(X_train, y_train)         knn.get_params(deep=True)  {'algorithm': 'auto', 'leaf_size': 30, 'metric': 'minkowski', 'metric_params': None, 'n_jobs': None, 'n_neighbors': 5, 'p':2,'weights': 'uniform'}

Comment: @Ins_hunter Oh I just saw your edit of this answer, seems the method 'get_dummies' works better for this question.

Comment: @Ins_hunter I think the KNN would belongs to another question.  I'm not familiar with it.  if it can not run, I can help you look in to what format it need, but if runs and you are not satisfied with the accuracy, I suggest you ask another question with KNN as tag, there would be expert there.  I'm not sure what's the best way to share the data, I think if you can share a clip on github that would work.

Comment: @fenixnano- Thanks for your response on the dummy variable(df.Genres.str.get_dummies(sep='|')        as i could complete the preprocessing and feed the model. For the KNN shall create a separate post . Thanks for the help.